# Wordpress Migration plan

Tags: wordpress, migration

Let's say I have an old wordpress site hosted at `abc.com`, where all the posts are written using visual editor. Now, we have decided to re-purpose old content and write everything in markdown.

Currently, `abc.com` has considerable amount of traffic as well as good ranking. So we can't modify the content while its live.

To make the process easier we have decided to replicate old site at `test.abc.com` (on the same server) and modify everything there.

Once everything is up to the mark, we change the document root of the Apache to point to the new Wordpress installation and change the Site Address (URL) in Setting via Dashboard.

So my question, How does this plan look?

Is there any potential pitfall that I need to be aware of ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress uses absolute URLs. Therefore you should search and replace every URL in the database from test.abc.com to abc.com before pointing Apache to that directory. Other than that you shouldn't face any problems.

Comment: You mean `wp search-replace 'http://example.dev' 'http://example.com' --skip-columns=guid` ? Am i right?

Comment: I usually use phpMyAdmin to run the SQL query.  **UPDATE `<table>` SET guid = REPLACE(guid, '<Old URL>', '<New URL>') WHERE `guid` LIKE '<Old URL>/%';**